# Sub query with not equal

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

Sub query with not equal

```
table_1


col1
SV0362
RU0177CSPG
NO0124CSPG
VN3582
AT9923CSPG
BZ0324
PE0309
AS4293EXPT
ML0331OMKT

table 2

colA
OO56128665
OO56128665
OO56128665
OO56128665
US0170
US0170
US0170
US0170
US0170
US0170
US0170
US0170
US0170
US0170
OO56128665
OO56128665
```

I want to compare col1 of table1 with colA of table 2 and return the values which are not qual

something like this

select * from table1  where col1 <> (select colA from table_2 a,table1 b where  b.col1=a.colA)

but this would give single row returns more than one subquery

Comment: Did you try  using `not in` instead of `<>` ?

Comment: But you want retrun values only from col1 of table1?

Comment: MINUS is designed for this kind of problems. right?

Comment: @miracl173 :yes

Comment: Do you want to return values form ***both*** tables that have no match in the other table?  Or just the values from table1.col1 that are not in table2.colA?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT colA FROM table_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want rows from table 1 that does not exist in table_2 and vice versa:

```
SELECT col1, 'table_1' as origin
FROM table_1 x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table_2 y
    WHERE x.col1 = y.cola
)
UNION
SELECT cola, 'table_2' as origin
FROM table_2 x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table_1 y
    WHERE y.col1 = x.cola
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle `MINUS`, `UNION` and `INTERSECT` also to achieve the same. It is an another way to solve.

i.e. ( A - B ) ∪ ( B - A ) = ( A ∪ B ) - ( A ∩ B )

```
( select col1  from table_1
   union
  select cola  from table_2
)
minus
( select col1 from table_1
   intersect
  select cola from table_2
);
```

You can very well use IN or EXISTS in the subqueries also.

```
( select col1
from table_1
union
select cola
  from table_2
)
minus
( select col1
    from table_1
   where exists ( select 1
                    from table_2
                   where table_1.col1 = table_2.cola
)
);
```

This SQL Tutorial explains the [EXISTS](https://sqltutorial.tips/2018/10/sql-exists.html), NOT EXISTS usage.

Comment: Not bad but you could use JOIN instead of the EXISTS subquery or even better INTERSECT, to match the set operators in your formula.

Comment: Thanks @ypercubeᵀᴹ . :-) I modified the answer.